# Call a html page inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a calendar with javascript.. I am trying than when click to a data to open another html page...What I have done till now is that when I click a date it gives me an alert message... I want that instead of alert message to open a html page at my function...So how can I open `calendar2.html` inside my function below:

```
g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
            var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();
            alert("a date was just selected and the date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);
            document.getElementById("div3_example_result").innerHTML = obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year;
        });
```

What to put instead of:

```
 `alert("a date was just selected and the date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);`
```

Thanks in advance for helping me!

I put the row like below but it does not function ...Where to put it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){


        g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
            useMode:1,
            isStripped:true,
            target:"div3_example"

        });     

        $('#div3_example_result').load('index.html');

        g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
            var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();
            alert("a date was just selected and the date is : " + obj.day + "/"            + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);

            document.getElementById("div3_example_result").innerHTML = obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year;
        });

        };

</script>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="div3_example" style="margin:10px 0 30px 0; border:dashed 1px red; width:205px; height:230px;">

    </div>                

    <div id="div3_example_result" style="height:20px; line-height:20px; margin:10px 0 0 0; border:dashed 1px #666;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div3_example_result').load('calendar2.html');
```

https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: but where to put these row...i put it like above but when I click one day it does not take me to another page...please help me

Comment: can you help me...what can I do?

Comment: is anyone there to help me, or is my question too silly?